# Use deductions guides in implicit argument conversion

Tags: c++, c++17, implicit-conversion

Consider the following mock of type definitions:

```
template<typename T> struct Foo {};

template<typename T, size_t offset>
struct FooView {
    FooView(const Foo<T>&) {}
};
template<typename T> FooView(const Foo<T>&) -> FooView<T, 0>;

template<typename T, size_t s>
void yada(FooView<T, s> arg) {}
```

As one can see, we have a type `Foo`, here representing a collection of things `T` and a type `FooView` which shall represent a view into a Foo, together with some offset `s` (the nature of the offset is not that important). It also offers a deduction guide, from a `Foo` to a `FooView` with `offset = 0`.

Now, consider how this is is used:

```
Foo<float> foo;
// yada(foo); // <-- error: no matching function for call to 'yada'
yada(FooView{foo});
```

I would have thought that the implicit constructor paired with the deduction guide was enough to make the commented call work, but I actually have to type out the conversion. Can I somehow make this implicitly convertible?

I have tried introducing an implicit conversion operator in `Foo` like this:

```
operator FooView<T, 0>() { return FooView{*this}; }
```

but to no avail. The compiler still throws the same error.

Comment: godbolt link https://godbolt.org/g/7BBUU8

Comment: maybe there is a typo in the code? `Bar` in place of `FooView`, maybe?

Comment: @ArdaAytekin yeah forgot to copy that back from godbolt

Comment: Template argument deduction does not consider possible conversions. `foo` is not a "FooView<T,s>" so template argument deduction fails to deduce template arguments of `yada`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class template argument deduction only applies in [certain situations](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.class.deduct), which all require the actual class template placeholder to be used. `arg` does not trigger deduction, only `cls(arg)` does.

`yada(foo)` just follows the normal rules of overload resolution, and since `foo` is not a `FooView` (template deduction doesn't consider conversions), overload resolution fails.

`yada(FooView(foo))` does class template argument deduction *because you asked for it*. This is always an explicit, on-demand feature.

Comment: I'll spell out the trivial function overload then. A bit tedious but still better than at every usage.

Comment: @WorldSEnder If you want conversions, you always need to spell them out. Templates match, they don't convert.